# Highlight one of three paragraphs if clicked (deselecting the others while at it)

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, tabs, smarty

I have three paragraphs which are made to look like three seperate buttons:

```
<p id="showCloud" class="newRefreshThree" name="tabbed"><span class="ico"></span><a href="">{i18n key="evadmin.title.cloud"}</a></p>

{if $enableCapacityReport=="1"}

<p id="showStats" name="tabbed"><span class="ico"></span><a href="" >{i18n key="evadmin.stats.showstats"}</a></p>

{/if}

<p id="showInfrastructure"  name="tabbed" class="newRefreshFour"><span class="ico"></span><a href="">{i18n key="evadmin.title.infrastructure"}</a></p>
```

All of them share the same name, `name = tabbed`

Each of these paragraphs/buttons send a user to a seperate tab and I would like to highlight the button of whichever tab is selected, while making sure all the other types are then un-highlighted.

Just now I wrote what I thought was the first part of the JQuery I need:

```
$('p[name=tabbed]').click(function(){
        $(this).css('background-color','red');
        });
```

but obviously this doesn't deselect the other p's, and I didn't know the most efficient/nicest way of doing it..

Also I would like to have an initial button/p highlighted when the page orignally loads so that it starts off highlighted for that tab.

Could anyone recommend to me what event/method I can use to do everything I just stated, or even give an example? Regards

Comment: You would be far better off doing this with some style rules...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're not going to be dynamically adding `<p>` elements to the page, then you can cache the selector, use that to manipulate **all** of the paragraphs, then finally apply your style to the element that was clicked on.

```
var $p = $('p[name="tabbed"]');
$p.click(function(e) {
    $p.css('background-color', '');
    $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
});
```

Or, use a CSS class declaration, and use the `removeClass()` and `addClass()` functions to add/remove that class as appropriate:

CSS
    .red {
        background-color: red;
    }

jQuery:

```
var $p = $('p[name="tabbed"]');
$p.click(function(e) {
    $p.removeClass('red');
    $(this).addClass('red');
});
```

Comment: If you can't edit the HTML then it would be easiest to just simulate a click on that element - `$('#showCloud').click();` - after binding the click event handler.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('p[name=tabbed]').click(function(){
    $('p[name=tabbed]').not(this).css({ background: 'none' });
    $(this).css('background-color','red');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that:

```
$('p[name=tabbed]').click(function(){
        $('p[name=tabbed]').css('background-color','transparent');
        $(this).css('background-color','red');
        });
```

But better would be to use css class.